# /usr/bin/curator giving error "Fatal error: unable to stat executable"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch-curator on a new AWS EC2 instance on which root volume is EBS and CentOS version is 6.9.
When i run the /usr/bin/curator command it given me below error:

```
[root@elasticsearch-02 ~]# /usr/bin/curator
Fatal error: unable to stat executable
```

Can someone please help and tell me what could be the issue here.

Comment: What happens if you type `stat /usr/bin/curator`?

Comment: Here is the output:
```
[root@ elasticsearch-02 ~]# stat /usr/bin/curator
  File: `/usr/bin/curator' -> `/opt/elasticsearch-curator/curator'
  Size: 34         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: fd00h/64768d Inode: 27670       Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-01-28 09:11:34.961480364 +0000
Modify: 2018-01-26 17:20:11.799361564 +0000
Change: 2018-01-26 17:20:11.799361564 +0000
```

Comment: No obvious problem noted, there, so next `stat /opt/elasticsearch-curator/curator`.

Comment: Output:
<production>[root@prod-indexer-elastic-us-east-1e-30.mashery.com ~]# stat /opt/elasticsearch-curator/curator
  File: `/opt/elasticsearch-curator/curator'
  Size: 2633352    Blocks: 5144       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d Inode: 26889       Links: 1
Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-01-28 19:05:01.852312531 +0000
Modify: 2017-01-27 23:37:12.000000000 +0000
Change: 2018-01-26 17:20:11.284378415 +0000